# Unable to get Pwnhammer on Terraria on Android

Tags: terraria-mobile

I've killed the Wall of Flesh twice now on Android, but I've never been able to get or even see the Pwnhammer, so now I'm stuck and I can't get any better ores.

Comment: Make sure your version of Terraria is up to date. On Android, the minimum version that includes Hardmode content is **1.1.5822**.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the store from which you got the game and see if there is an update for it. If there isn't an update, you might have to uninstall and reinstall the game(Unwished).